# Undefined method `type' for Polymorphic Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations

Undefined method `type' for Polymorphic Association.

My Polymorphic association with the models Follow, Dad and Mom gives me an error when writing a method to see if a user is already following one of them.

Here are all of my models and the method `following` which is the problem.

**Models**

```
class User
 has_many :follows

  def following?(followable)
    follows.where(followable_id: followable.id, followable_type: followable.type ).any?
  end
end

class Mom
  has_many :follows, as: :followable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Dad
  has_many :follows, as: :followable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**Controller**

```
@dad = Dad.find(params[:dad_id])
```

**View**

```
<% unless current_user.following?(@dad) %>
  <%= link_to({ controller: 'follows', action: 'create', id: @dad.id }, { method: :post }) do %>
    Follow
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Error**

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `type' for #<Dad:0xaf63038>:
  activemodel (4.0.2) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:439:in `method_missing'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:155:in `method_missing'
  app/models/user.rb:17:in `following?'
  .................
```

This works if I get rid of `followable_type` but that removes the reason for the method. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is the problem

```
follows.where(followable_id: followable.id, followable_type: followable.type ).any?
```

Replace `followable.type` with `followable.class.name`

`type` used to be a synonym for `class` but this was deprecated.  Even if it hadn't been deprecated, you need to find records where followable_type is the **name** of the class, not the class itself.

Answer (score 1):

@MaxWilliams is correct although if you still want to use `type` you just need to include the method in your model

```
module Typeify
  def type
    self.class.name
  end
end
class Mom
  include Typeify
end 
class Dad
  include Typeify
end
```